# SQLite3 SQL DELETE syntax for two WHERE columns

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

This string works perfect for one column:

```
delSQL = "DELETE FROM user WHERE Name='" + datArray[0] + "';";
```

But what looks correct for two columns has error: expected ‘;’ before ‘AND’

```
delSQL = "DELETE FROM user WHERE Name='" + datArray[0] + "'" AND " Age=" + datArray[1] + ";";
```

Advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
delSQL = "DELETE FROM user WHERE Name='" + datArray[0] + "' AND Age=" + datArray[1] + ";";
```

Comment: Thank you Pons! I wrongly had it in my mind that the AND needed to be freestanding.